# $http.post cross domain request not working in Internet explorer (Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied)

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, post, cors, preflight

When I make an $http.post request and set the "withCredentials" property to true.
My request works fine in Chrome and Fiefox. However, I'm getting the error below in IE:

XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied.

I noticed that if I enable the "Access data resources across domains" setting in IE, The error gets resolved. However I need to find an alternative solution because I can't ask the users to enable that setting obviously.

[image: IE Setting that fixes the issue]
I noticed that a $http.get request to the same domain is working in IE with no issue, the issue is only with the $http.post request, the Options request is getting a 500 internal server and I see the request and response headers below:

[image: request headers in IE]
[image: response headers in IE]
Note:
I do have the necessary custom headers, and I can see them in Chrome when the OPTIONS request succeeds. The headers that I see in Chrome are listed below:

[image: Chrome request and response headers]

Could you please let me know if I'm missing something that would make the request work in IE without having to enable Access data sources across domains?

Comment: What version of IE are you testing on?

Comment: It's IE 11 , but I tried switching to IE 10,9,8,7 in the debugger's emulator tab and I get the same error

Comment: Clearly your server isn't responding to the OPTIONS request properly. fix the server.

Comment: Have you diagnosed why the server is responding with a 500 response yet? that's a pretty important piece of information.

Comment: But the server is responding with 200 to the same request in Chrome, and it responds with 200 to the same request in IE with the "access data sources across domains" enabled, so it seems fine

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer 9 doesn't support cookies in CORS requests. The `withCredentials` property of the `$http` arguments attempts to send cookies. I don't think there's any way to fix it with headers. IE10+ *should* work by default, just be sure that you are not in compatibility mode. CORS isn't fully implemented in IE10 either, but the type of request you are trying to do should work.

You didn't mention what the nature of your web app is, but it impacts the type of workaround you will need for IE9. If possible, see if you can refactor your code to use a GET request instead (again, I don't know what you are trying to do via AJAX so this may be impossible).

You may be able to use [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com) or something similar to detect if the browser supports CORS. If it is not supported, send the request without AJAX and have a page refresh.

Another alternative if you really want to use AJAX is to set up a proxy on your web server, i.e. the server on the same domain. Instead of making the cross-origin request directly, you make the AJAX request to your same-origin server, which then makes the request to the cross-origin server for you. The server won't have CORS issues. This solution assumes, of course, that you have some server-side scripting going on such as PHP, Node or Java.

Comment: The type of request that the OP asked about won't work with the default IE9 settings. Not sure how anything I said was inaccurate in this context.

Comment: Specifically it is the use of cookies (withCredentials in Angular). See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941281/make-a-cors-request-in-ie9-with-cookies

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my issue isn't just with IE 9. You mentioned that it should work with IE 10+ by default, but it doesn't. In IE Emulation, I do see it says Document Mode (10 Default)  via X-UA Compatible meta tag. Not sure if that has anything to do with the issue.

Comment: I'm also confused as to why enable the access data sources across domains setting fixes the issue